# Scala Case Class equals implementation

Tags: scala, equals

Given the following the classes:

```
trait ModelWithId {
  var id: Long = 0
}
case class EntityAttribute  (
  val entityId: UUID,
  val attrName: String,
  val stringVal: Option[String],
  val boolVal: Option[Boolean],
  val longVal: Option[Long],
  val doubleVal: Option[Double],
  val byteVal: Option[Array[Byte]]) extends ModelWithId{
  override def toString() : String = {
"EntityAttribute(" + entityId.hashCode + "," + attrName.hashCode + "," +
  stringVal.map{_.hashCode}.getOrElse(None) + "," + stringVal.hashCode+ "," +
  boolVal.map{_.hashCode}.getOrElse(None) + "," + boolVal.hashCode+ "," +
  longVal.map{_.hashCode}.getOrElse(None) + "," + longVal.hashCode+ "," +
  doubleVal.map{_.hashCode}.getOrElse(None) + "," + doubleVal.hashCode+ "," +
  byteVal.map{_.hashCode}.getOrElse(None) +  ")"
  }
}
```

And the following comparison functions:

```
val newAtttributes : List[EntityAttribute]
val withoutIds : List[EntityAttribute]

println("without: " + withoutIds)
println("new:     " + newAtttributes)

  val differences = newAtttributes.diff(withoutIds)
  println("diff:    " + differences)
  if(newAtttributes.size == 1 && withoutIds.size == 1){
    println("==:      " + (newAtttributes.get(0) == withoutIds.get(0)))
    println("equals:  " + (newAtttributes.get(0).equals(withoutIds.get(0))))
    println("hequals: " + (newAtttributes.get(0).hashCode == withoutIds.get(0).hashCode))
  }
```

I get the expected difference output 99 out 100 times. Very occasionally the diff function will return an empty list when it should a list of one.

Example:

```
without: List(EntityAttribute(428861607,-1147340381,None,120224,None,120224,56,-356863126,None,120224,None))
new:     List(EntityAttribute(428861607,-1147340381,None,120224,None,120224,23,424930523,None,120224,None))
diff:    List()
==:      false
equals:  false
hequals: false
```

I can reliably reproduce this error usually after around 10-18 iterations. The two lists are coming from different sources, so they are being constructed differently. I am guessing that it has something to do with auto-boxing or a bad hashCode implementation but I have been bashing my head into a wall for 2 days without progress.

I'm using scala 2.9.0-1.

Comment: You could print the actual value, so that we could actually reproduce the problem...

Comment: didn't you forget a `}`after `extends ModelWithId{`?

Answer (score -1):

Those two `EntityAttribute`'s contain different values for `longVal`.  The default `equals` implementation for case classes takes all members into account, so that makes them unequal.  If you want to only use a subset of the members you should define your own `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Exactly, so diff should be a list of size one.